# iOS top left back button without visible navigation bar

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uikit

*I am developping an iOS application with UIKit and a Storyboard in Xcode 11.1.*

I have a `ViewController` (embedded in a `Navigation Controller`) that contains a fullscreen `MKMapView`. I would really like this `MKMapView` to take as much space as possible, so I choose to hide the navigation bar of the `Navigation Controller`. However from the `View Controller` I push another `View Controller`, but as the navigation bar is hidden, this pushed `View Controller` has no back button in the top left corner because the previous `View Controller` has no / a hidden navigation bar.

**How can I make the back button on the pushed `View Controller` visible without having to make the navigation bar on the `View Controller` it is being pushed from visible?**

I would not like to hardcode some button on the second, pushed `View Controller`, as it is also accessed by other `View Controller`s, which have a visible navigation bar and thus the back button is shown for them

Here is a small diagram that shows my setup.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this to your view controller that contains MKMapView & has no navigationBar:

```
 override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: animated)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I can't believe I did not think of this. If anyone else implements this, 1) dont forget to set the navigationBarHidden to true again in the viewWillAppear, and 2) it seems to work best with animated set to true.